# Change the Word AddIn Ribbon Button tooltip text

Tags: c#, .net, office-interop, ribbon-control, word-addins

I need to change the word addin ribbon mouse over tool tip text by button name.Currently it is getting the text of project name for all the buttons in ribbon.

sample screen

[image]

I have changed the assembly name in project properties but nothing happened. But if I changed the friendly name in `.csproj` file it will changed. I want to know  that -this is the correct way to do by changing the `.csproj` file friendly name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it via project properties-> publish -> Options -> Office Settings and changed the name in to new one.

Then also changed the tool tip values in each ribbon button by go to Ribbon in design view and Select a Button => Properties => ScreenTip and SuperTip

Done.